# Find the average of each element in a list of arbitrarily nested lists

Tags: list, python-3.x, recursion, average, nested-lists

I'm trying to make a function that takes a list with elements that are either floats or arbitrarily nested list of floats, and returns a list of the same length with each element replaced by its average.

ie. 
`lst = [1,[2,[3,[4,[5]]]]] #average of lst[0] = 1 average of lst[1] = (((((4+5)/2)+3)/2)+2)/2
print(Avg(lst))`
which should print [1,2.875]
here's what I got so far:

```
def Avg(lst,n=1):
    if lst = [] and n > 1:
        return 0
    elif lst = []:
        return lst
    elif type(lst) == float:
        return lst
    elif type(lst[0]) == float and n > 1:
        return (lst[0] + Avg(lst[1:]))/len(lst)
    elif type(lst[0]) == list:
        total = 0
        length = 0
        for e in lst[0]:
            total += Avg(e)
            length += 1
        return [total/length] + Avg(lst[1:])
    return [lst[0]] + Avg(lst[1:])
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose the route of iterating through the lists, and using recursion if the current element was itself a list.  I only checked for `float` or `int` to determine if something was numeric, but that's easily extended if need be since it's isolated in a function.

Without further ado:

```
def is_numeric(item):
    return type(item) == float or type(item) == int

def Avg(something):
    if is_numeric(something):
        return something
    for i, element in enumerate(something):
        if not is_numeric(element):
            sub_element = Avg(element)
            l = len(sub_element)
            something[i] = sum(sub_element) / l if l > 0 else 0
    return something

print(Avg([1,[2,[3,[4,[5]]]]]))
```

produces `[1, 2.875]`.